# Using Javascript To Show Values From HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a HTML Page with multiple forms, and I would like
to show the values from the form on the same page (wiping the original HTML), but after using the button, nothing shows up (the page like reloaded)

Here's the code for HTML :

```js
function Results() {
  var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
  var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
  var gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
  var date = document.getElementById('birthday').value;

  if (document.getElementById('genderM').checked) {
      gender = document.getElementById('genderM').value;
    } else if (document.getElementById('genderF').checked) {
        gender = document.getElementById('genderF').value;
      }

      document.writeIn("<h3>Thank You! Here's Your Precious Data! </h3>"); document.writeIn("<p> Your Name Is : </p>" + fname + lname); document.writeIn("<p> Gender : " + gender); document.writeIn("<p> Birthday : " + birthday);

      document.getElementById('forms').innerHTML = forms;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title> The Page Number 2 </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page2.css">

</head>

<body>

  <h1> Please fill in the form for exciting contents! </h1>

  <hr size="5px" color="black">

  <div id="forms" class="forms">
    <form onsubmit="Results()" method="post">

      <div class="textFirst">
        First Name
      </div>

      <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname"> <br>

      <br>
      <div class="textLast">
        Last Name <br>
      </div>

      <input id="lname" type="text" name="lname"> <br>

      <br>

      <div class="textGender">
        Gender <br>
        <input id="genderM" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male <br>
        <input id="genderF" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female <br>
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="textBirth">
        Birthday <br>
      </div>

      <input id="birthday" type="date" name="birthday"> <br>


  <input id="submit" class="buttonagain" type="submit" value="Submit!" />

  </form>
  
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Any ideas what should I do?

Edit : I'm not able to use php or server for this

Comment: Yes, the page is reloaded, that's the default response from your server when submitting a form. And what should you do ... Don't submit the form.

Comment: their is a lot of error in your code , the submit is not the only issue

Comment: I changed the input type to button, but nothing happened. Is there any errors?

Comment: Please review my answer and please comment on it to tell my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your code is riddled with syntax errors: missing parentheses, missing + operators, etc.
2. `document.writeIn` (with an uppercase I) is not a function; `document.writeln` (with a lowercase L) is.
3. `<script>` tags aren't self-closing, i.e. you have to write `<script src="scriptPage2.js"></script>`
4. `document.getElementById('gender')` returns `null`, because there is no element with `id="gender"`.
5. You're trying to write `birthday` but you never declared that variable.
6. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with `document.getElementById('forms').innerHTML = forms;`

In general, you should make use of the browser's built-in debugger to catch all these errors. If you're using Chrome or Firefox, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (in IE or Edge, press <kbd>F12</kbd>) and open the "Console" tab; you will see all the errors there as the JS parser encounters them.

Once that's all fixed, remove the submit event handler from `<form>`, and change your submit button like this:

```
<input id="submit" class="buttonagain" type="button" onclick="Results()" value="Submit!" />
```

Note the change of `type` from **`submit`** to **`button`**. This will prevent the page from reloading, which is the expected behavior when submitting a form.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but still, nothing happened. No value showed up

Comment: Updated my answer with more details

Comment: Well that was very embarassing. 
You were right : there's lots of syntax error in the JS.

Thanks for the advise!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `return` and `;` when calling a js function in html

```
<form onsubmit="Results()" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer.

```js
function Results() {
      var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
      var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
      var gender;
      var date = document.getElementById('birthday').value;
 
if (document.getElementById('genderM').checked) {
gender = "Male";
} else {
gender = "Female"
}

          document.writeln("<h3>Thank You! Here's Your Precious Data! </h3>");
          document.writeln("<p> Your Name Is : </p>" + fname + " " + lname); 
          document.writeln("<p> Gender : " + gender); 
          document.writeln("<p> Birthday : " + date);

          document.getElementById('forms').style.display = "none";
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>

    <head>
      <title> The Page Number 2 </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page2.css">

    </head>

    <body>

      <h1> Please fill in the form for exciting contents! </h1>

      <hr size="5px" color="black">

      <div id="forms" class="forms">
        <form onsubmit="Results();" method="post">

          <div class="textFirst">
            First Name
          </div>

          <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" required> <br>

          <br>
          <div class="textLast">
            Last Name <br>
          </div>

          <input id="lname" type="text" name="lname"required> <br>

          <br>

          <div class="textGender">
            Gender <br>
            <input id="genderM" type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required> Male <br>
            <input id="genderF" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female <br>
          </div>

          <br>

          <div class="textBirth">
            Birthday <br>
          </div>
          <input id="birthday" type="date" name="birthday"required> <br>
      </div>


      <input id="submit" class="buttonagain" type="submit" value="Submit!" />

      </div>


      </form>



    </body>

    </html>
```